# selected item of dropdownlist display text on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i want to display a text when user selects an item of dropdownlist. On page by default all text is displayed but if user selects an item from dropdown list then only the focus goes to perticular text section. In code if i select 'a' item then on page focus goes to 'a' item text. I don't know how to do it in javascript ,can anyone please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ChangeText()
{
var parm = document.getElementById("mySelection");
document.getElementById('lbltxt').innerHTML = parm.options[parm.selectedIndex].text; 

}
</Script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="mySelection" onchange="Return ChangeText();" style="width:30%;">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select method</option>
  <option value="1">a (new version)</option>
  <option value="2">b (old version)</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<b><label id="lblid" /></b><br /><br />
<strong id="1">A(For new versions)</strong><br />
In a, This can be done by denying the OPTIONS verb from the HTTP Verb Request Filtering rules in IIS.Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content<br />

<img src="images/1.png" style="float:left;"><img style="float:left;" src="images/arrow_up.png" width="62" height="60">Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content<br />
<br />
<strong id="2">b (For old versions)</strong><br />
  for B :<br />
Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content
<img src="images/2.png">Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content<br /><br />
<strong id="3">C</strong><br />
<p style="text-align:justify; font-size:17px;">Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your vascript - what you have so far

Comment: i don't used js, actually i really don't know how to do this in js

Comment: you need to read up on it then , try to do it on your own , watch some tutorials , then come back when you are having specific problems , paste your code and explain your problem.  This ist really the place to just put your specs and have someone do it for you

Comment: @sandysharma: what exactly you want to do ? what you tried so far??  On dropdown selection If you just want to set **focus**  on respected text, then use `.focus()` method , or if you want to **hide/show** text based on selection, then check `.hide(), .show()` method  of jQuery

Comment: by default all text displayed on page. but if i select any item from dropdown list, then text should displayed related to selected item @ Satinder singh

Answer (score 1):

First you should call a javascript function In the OnChange() event of the Dropdown
Then You can Add a label in the position of text you want.
You can Set the text for the page load (All items) for the label.
Then , in the javascript (Called when the drop down changed), 
You can alter the Label Text According to the drop down selection.

In the Page Loading itself you can assign the values for the label, as you want all.

```js
              function ChangeText()
                        {
                          var contentText;
                          var selectedITem='';
                        var parm = document.getElementById("mySelection");
                          selectedITem =parm.options[parm.selectedIndex].text;
                          if(selectedITem == 'a')
                            contentText = 'Type What you want for option A'
                         else  if(selectedITem == 'b')
                            contentText = 'Type What you want for option B'
                          
                          
    str='<tr> <td>'  +  contentText +' </td> </tr>';
     $("#test").append(str);
                          

                        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table id="test">
              
              <tr>
              
            <td width="40%" align="left">
                                                
             <select id="mySelection" onchange="ChangeText();" style="width: 100%;">
               
             <option disabled="disabled"   selected="selected">Select method</option>
                  <option value="1">a</option>
                  <option value="2">b</option>
                  <option value="3">c</option>
                   </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </td>


              </tr>
              
              </table>
```

Comment: sorry for asking but the id 'lbltxt', in function where you have used in code & what is 'lblid'?

Comment: Ok you want to show some text right? That one we can assign to a label, that label you can placed where you want to add text, then That id is user defined, that id helps to Change the text of label (Label is used for showing some texts !)

Comment: please show it if possible show on snippet @BOBIN JOSEPH

Comment: Is that you exactly want? Right? iam added in the code snippet? Check it And page load you can add what ever the value you want. iam removed the label and added that into a <td> :) :) :) You added it in your code and modify as you needed.

Comment: almost. but instead of hiding previous text, i want to show it on page. if 'b' item is selected then under item 'a' text, display items 'b' text. it won't hide item 'a's text. it should on page. this is what i want@ BOBIN JOSEPH

Comment: Iam added you just check it... and iam added the jquery header check it... it is slow... Modify as ur needs..

Comment: i don't want to show the item name. i want their respective text. by default all items text are shown but if i select item 'c', then  item 'c's text is showed(cursor pointing to item 'c' text) . at the same time remaining text is also displayed.

Comment: yet u didn't understand my requirement brother.

Comment: Oh you want the text box with the selected item's respective text..! Anyway em tired sister  :( sorry....  ! em not pretty good at this all.. anyay i hope it helped some way... If you dont get any better solution than this, then mark it as CORRECT.. ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write following code in js, hopefully it will work fine.

```
$("#mySelection").on('change', function() {
  id = $(this).val();
  window.location.hash = "#"+id;
})
```

Comment: don't condone questions that arent even going to attempt on their own.

Comment: it's a quick way to get points but brings the overall quality of the site down

Comment: I mean, use this code, hopefully it will work fine @sandysharma

Comment: brother is not working, can you please add  your code in snippet@Sarwan Kumar.

Comment: For the above code, you would need to include JQuery, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: how to add jquery to get result mean jquery version @ ABHILASH SB

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="mySelection" style="width:30%;">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected>Select method</option>
    <option value="1">a (new version)</option>
    <option value="2">b (old version)</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select><br /><br />

<table>
    <tr id="1" class="user">
        <td class="img">
            <img src="images/1.png" width="62" height="60"></td>
        <td class="description">
            <p><strong>A(For new versions)</strong></p>
            <p>In a, This can be done by denying the OPTIONS verb from the HTTP Verb Request Filtering rules in IIS.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="user">
        <td class="img">
            <img src="images/arrow_up.png" width="62" height="60">
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <p><strong>b (For old versions)</strong></p>
            <p>for B :<br />Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="user">
        <td class="img">
            <img src="images/2.png" width="62" height="60">
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <p><strong>C</strong></p>
            <p>Following is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML contentFollowing is an example which makes use of .html() and .text(val) methods. Here .html() retrieves HTML content</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
    table{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    table td{
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .user{
        display: none;
    }
```

Script

```
$("#mySelection").on('change', function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('#'+id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, If I understand what you are trying to do, simply correct your "onchange" call, and I don't see any element with id="lbltxt" so I've added one:
Change this part of your code:

```
<body>
    <select id="mySelection" onchange="ChangeText();" style="width:30%;">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select method</option>
        <option value="1">a (new version)</option>
        <option value="2">b (old version)</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
    </select>

    <b><label id="lblid" /></b><br /><br />
    //added element
    <div id="lbltxt" ></div><br /><br /> 
    .....
```

and if you want also to "scroll" to that item you should modify your js function like this:

```
function ChangeText()
        {
            var parm = document.getElementById("mySelection");
            document.getElementById('lbltxt').innerHTML = parm.options[parm.selectedIndex].text;
            window.location.hash = "#" + parm.value;
        }
```